# What is a chief series of a group $H=(\mathbb{Q}_8 \rtimes C_3 ) \times A_5$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, semidirect-product

The definition of [Chief series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_series) is given in a link.

Question:

> Consider the group G= $\mathbb{Q}_8 \rtimes C_3 $ (where the action is non trivial), its chief series is $$ e \triangleleft Z_2 \triangleleft \mathbb{Q}_8 \triangleleft G.$$
>
> Is the following a Chief series for the group $H=(\mathbb{Q}_8 \rtimes C_3 ) \times A_5$?
>
> $$ e \triangleleft (e \times A_5) \triangleleft (Z_2 \times A_5) \triangleleft  (\mathbb{Q}_8 \times A_5)  \triangleleft H.$$

If this is a chief series for $H$ then my question is why?
If this is not then what is a correct series?

Thanks!

Edit: As @Derek Holt suggested, I have made changes in the question. Thank you!

Comment: This group has more than one chief series, so you cannot say that your series is "the" chief series - it is "a" chief series. You have not specified the action in the semidirect product, but assuming that this is a nontrivial action (i.e. it is not a direct product), then yes, this is indeed a chief series. The reason is that the series cannot be refined - i.e. you cannot insert any further normal subgroups of $G$ that lie strictly between two terms of your series.